# How to edit react content dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Ok..first things first:
Please refer the image of webApp attached:
My Application displays loginIdCard's consisting(website,username,password) from mongoDb which
i can edit from react when clicking on edit button.
What i did is initially i maintained a editMode key in component state a set it as false.
when a user clicks on edit button the LoginIdCard becomes editable and on clicking save button new values are set in component state and then editLoginId function is dispatch which updates this new value in database.
Now,
following are the things i want:

1. Initially when edit button is clicked, the value inside the input field should be the original values,
   but now it is show empty.
   2.The new values should be displayed immediately without rerendering of component.

Note: Now,after cliciking on save button , the component rerenders and the endpoint api return res data which is not a array, so the LoginDisplay component is not able to map and gives this.map is not a function error.

Please Help me

[Web app rendering LoginIdCard in LoginDisplay Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYkHf.png)

```js
"LoginDispaly Component:Here LoginIdCard Component Will Rendender"


import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import LoginIdCard from "./LoginIdCard";
import EditLoginIdComponent from "./EditLoginIdComponent";
import { fetchLoginIds } from "../actions/loginInIdsAction";
import "../css/displaySection.css";

class LoginsDisplay extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchLoginIds();
  }

  render() {
    const { logins } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="display-section">
        {logins.map((logins) => (
          <LoginIdCard logins={logins} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    logins: state.logins.logins,
  };
}
LoginsDisplay.propTypes = {
  logins: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchLoginIds })(LoginsDisplay);
```

```js
"LoginIdCard Component it will be render in LoginDispaly Component"

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { editLoginId } from "../actions/loginInIdsAction";
import "../css/card.css";

class LoginIdCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      website: "",
      username: "",
      password: "",
      editMode: false,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    // this.handleSave = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange = (fieldName, val) => {
    console.log(val);
    this.setState({
    
      [fieldName]: val,
    });
  };

  handleSave = () => {
    const { website, username, password } = this.state;
    const { logins } = this.props;
    this.props.dispatch(editLoginId(website, username, password, logins._id));
    console.log(this.state.website, username, password, logins._id);
  };

  render() {
    const { editMode } = this.state;
    const { logins } = this.props;
    // const website = logins.website;
    // const username = logins.username;
    // const password = logins.password;

    return (
      <div className="card">
        {editMode ? (
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange("website", e.target.value)}
            value={this.state.website}
          />
        ) : (
          <p>{this.state.website}</p>
        )}
        {editMode ? (
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange("username", e.target.value)}
            value={this.state.username}
          />
        ) : (
          <p>{logins.username}</p>
        )}
        {editMode ? (
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange("password", e.target.value)}
            value={this.state.password}
          />
        ) : (
          <p>{logins.password}</p>
        )}
        {editMode ? (
          <button onClick={this.handleSave}>save</button>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={() => this.handleChange("editMode", true)}>
            edit
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// this.handleChange("editMode", false)
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    // user: state.user.users,
    // cards: state.cards.cards,
    logins: state.logins.logins,
  };
}
// App.propTypes = {
//   user: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
// };

export default connect()(LoginIdCard);
```

```js
"redux action file for editing the LoginId in mongodb"
export function editLoginId(website, username, password, id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    const req = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        website: website,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        cardId: id,
      }),
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:9000/editLoginId", req)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) =>
        dispatch({
          type: EDIT_LOGIN_ID,
          payload: data,
        })
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
      });
  };
}
```